# Javascript best way to filter out empty values or function fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, filter

Hello I have this function that takes array of objects and takes a specific value from the object and creates array of strings that can make mapped to dropdown selector.

```js
const value = {
  Value: [{
      "Activity Id": "04912309-35",
      "Activity Name": "SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-30 08:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "READY",
      crew: "FIN",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 EN RS NR",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "RHR*SWPUMPDSCHSTOP*Z",
      "Activity Name": "MM 1E12-F332D CLEAN UP AFTER  DISASSEMBLE/INSPECT/REPAIR VALVE",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-07-09 08:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PME1",
      "Unit ": "02",
      Status: "WORKING",
      crew: "FIN",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F1 RM L2 NR",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "01322927-01B",
      "Activity Name": "2DG024 WALK C/O, DISASSEMBLE VALVE",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 16:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "ES MM",
      "Unit ": "02",
      Status: "H/APPR",
      crew: "FIN",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 WE RS NR L1 HS",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "01881463-01Z",
      "Activity Name": "MM 2CP40MD CLEAN UP AFTER REPLACE FILTER ELEMENT",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 20:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PME1",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "PLAN",
      crew: "",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 EN RS NR",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "DG*VLV*BRIDGES*BN",
      "Activity Name": "MM 2E22-S001 FILL ENGINE OIL",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 14:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "MM",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "",
      crew: "",
      "Work Pln Factor": "RM",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "04912309-3434",
      "Activity Name": "MM 2E22-S001 FILL ENGINE OIL zzzz",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "",
      crew: "",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 WE RS NR L1 H",
    },
  ];
}


const dataFilterArray = (data: any, str: string) => {
  const value: any = _.uniqBy(data, str);
  let newValue = value.map((each: any) => {
    const data = each[str].split(' ');
    return _.uniqBy(data, str);
  });
  newValue.push(`Select All`);
  newValue = newValue.flat(1);
  return newValue.filter((each: any) => each.length !== 0);
};


console.log(dataFilterArray(value.Value, 'Work Group Name'))

console.log(dataFilterArray(data, 'crew'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify the dataFilterArray. I feel like they are shouldn't be a reason to use flat method. This function also handles filtering out empty values. I would also like to move lodash if that's possible.

Comment: Snippet's code is breaking.

Comment: It seems you are saying your code works, and are looking for simplification, getting rid of `flat`, considering lodash, ... etc, which is like asking for a code review. Consider posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ShravanDhar, The breaking code because of typescript syntax.

Comment: @trincot I didn't know that was even a thing thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a Set (a **unique** collection of elements).

```
const dataFilterArray = (data, str) => {
  let s = new Set();
  data.forEach(itm => {
    (itm[str] || '').split(' ').forEach(v => { 
      if(v.length !== 0) s.add(v); 
    });
  });
  return ['Select All'].concat([...s]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well  let me see if I understand. For a dropdown you need a key or id an value.
Then lets try somethin like this

```
const result = value.Value.map(res => {
      res = {key: res['Work Group Name'], value: res.crew };
      return res;
})

console.log(result);
```

With this map you are converting the original object to a key, value object.
this is an example that how to convert data, maybe is not the real solution but it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` will help here, as well as the common array-to-Set-to-array shuffle used for uniqueness.  `.filter (Boolean)` removes empty strings as well as null and undefined values.  (It would also remove zeros, so is not usually appropriate for lists of numbers.)

```js
const dataFilterArray = (xs, str) => [
  'Select All', 
  ... [... new Set (xs .flatMap (x => (x [str] || '') .split (' ')))] .filter (Boolean)
]

const value = {Value:[{"Activity Id":"04912309-35","Activity Name":"SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS","Start Date ":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","End Date":"2021-06-30 08:45:21","Work Group Name":"PSCF","Unit ":"01",Status:"READY",crew:"FIN","Work Pln Factor":"F2 EN RS NR"},{"Activity Id":"RHR*SWPUMPDSCHSTOP*Z","Activity Name":"MM 1E12-F332D CLEAN UP AFTER  DISASSEMBLE/INSPECT/REPAIR VALVE","Start Date ":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","End Date":"2021-07-09 08:45:21","Work Group Name":"PME1","Unit ":"02",Status:"WORKING",crew:"FIN","Work Pln Factor":"F1 RM L2 NR"},{"Activity Id":"01322927-01B","Activity Name":"2DG024 WALK C/O, DISASSEMBLE VALVE","Start Date ":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","End Date":"2021-06-29 16:45:21","Work Group Name":"ES MM","Unit ":"02",Status:"H/APPR",crew:"FIN","Work Pln Factor":"F2 WE RS NR L1 HS"},{"Activity Id":"01881463-01Z","Activity Name":"MM 2CP40MD CLEAN UP AFTER REPLACE FILTER ELEMENT","Start Date ":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","End Date":"2021-06-29 20:45:21","Work Group Name":"PME1","Unit ":"01",Status:"PLAN",crew:"","Work Pln Factor":"F2 EN RS NR"},{"Activity Id":"DG*VLV*BRIDGES*BN","Activity Name":"MM 2E22-S001 FILL ENGINE OIL","Start Date ":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","End Date":"2021-06-29 14:45:21","Work Group Name":"MM","Unit ":"01",Status:"",crew:"","Work Pln Factor":"RM"},{"Activity Id":"04912309-3434","Activity Name":"MM 2E22-S001 FILL ENGINE OIL zzzz","Start Date ":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","End Date":"2021-06-29 08:45:21","Work Group Name":"PSCF","Unit ":"01",Status:"",crew:"","Work Pln Factor":"F2 WE RS NR L1 H"}]}

console .log (dataFilterArray (value.Value, 'Work Group Name'))
console .log (dataFilterArray (value.Value, 'crew'))
```